# Oscillating loss in CNN

Tags: neural-network, convolutional-neural-network

So I designed my own CNN with 10 layers of convolutions and no maxpoolings or any other connections. When I ran it on a dataset I got the following loss curve (blue) the other one is accuracy vs number of epochs. What do you think might be the problem here? And how to rectify it?
[image]

**NOTE:** My data-set of size 20 due to lack of computational resources, so the oscillation is probably looking more prominent or happening in the first place.

Comment: Can you give more details about how you train it? Do you mean batch-size of 20 or total dataset? are you performing classification?

Comment: @n1k31t4 total size of 20

Comment: Adam is not a good choice in this case, just reduce the learning rate that will help

Answer (score 3):

Oscillating loss can be attributed to either of the following:

1. Learning rate: Reduce the learning rate so that the gradient descent doesn't overshoot the minima.
2. Optimizer: Choose [ADAM optimizer](https://machinelearningmastery.com/adam-optimization-algorithm-for-deep-learning/) over the others like SGD. It works well.

Comment: Yeah but I don't have computational power to run that many epochs to compensate for learning rate..As for backprop algorithm I will change that

Comment: You can run it on AWS or on google cloud where you can get enough compute power.

Comment: I generally agree that Adam is a good choice of optimizer. I often use Nadam, which incoporates both Nesterov acceleration and adaptive moments. Could you explain more about how adaptive moments relates to oscillating loss?